# DnD 5E Cleric Multi-Classing

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, multi-classing, cleric, spellcasting

If a cleric (or a wizard) multi classes in another spellcasting class, would it be fair for them to be able to swap out their secondary class spells? I'm guessing "no", but I feel like there's an argument to made for the opposite too. I play almost exclusively as clerics, and I'd just like more ways to defend myself without running in with weapons or relying on inflict wounds and guiding bolt.

Comment: Do you have access to the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide?  Welcome to RPGSE.  Please take the tour and visit the help to see how to get the most out of an SE formatted Q&A site.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I do not unfortunately. Sorry if my question is too open-ended, I just don't have an official answer.

Comment: OK, sorry about the lack of links there; [tour] and [help]. I think that if you can explain which domain of cleric that you are playing it might make a more concrete answer possible.  The other question I have is do you have access to Xanathar's Guide to Everything?  If not, it's OK, we just need to know what resources you have in order for the answer to match the options you have available.

Comment: Can you explain more specifically in your question what you mean by “swapping out” secondary class spells? It might be clearer is you had a specific example (“If have a multiclass Cleric/Wizard can I do <specific thing with spells>“)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fair is not a rule in the documentation

**But there are no published methods to allow re-spelling a character.**

There are many home-brews (changes to or additional rules) that allow players to re-work spells they know at level-ups or other points in an adventure.  But there is no allowance in the documentation that allows changes of know spells based on a subsequent multi-class decision.

If that *fair*?  That is wholly in the eyes of the individual.  In my opinion, it's always fair to follow the rules in the books.  I think that DM decisions on matters like these should be based around the current game and the player characters involved in total.  But the character should have received utility from the spells during their previous levels, so being able to change out all of them seems like a huge improvement to multi-classing.

Wizards are always a special case. Wizards have a huge selection of spells, but are limited by needing the spells to be in their book to be selected for daily use. The availability of spells in a setting is wholly dependent on the DM providing spell-books or scrolls that the wizard can use to add to their spell-book. In this case, would you think that multi-classing allows the wizard to find or create a wholly new spell-book?  The recently proposed variant rules for classes included spell versatility rules that let some classes replace spells at every long rest.  These rules were met with some hostility on the basis of how it improved other caster classes while not helping wizards.  https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf  I don't really have a source for the hostility other than participating on Reddit forums after the proposed changes came out.

Comment: Class Feature Variants UA adds a way to replace a spell on long rest to all spellcasting classes who learn their spells. So, there **are** published methods to change spell selection.

Comment: UA isn't a published rule.  It's another form of home brew.